# Mongoose projection condition for sub-documents as array

Tags: mongoose

I have a document like this:

```js
{
 banks : [
           {bank_name : 'bank1',
            transfers : [
                          {amount : 10,
                           reason : 'A'
                          },
                          {amount : 3,
                           reason : 'B'
                          }
                         ]
            }
         ]

}
```

I'd like to get all the transitions of all the banks, just with `reason == 'A'`. How can I do that?

I try something like :

```js
Model.aggregate().match()
                .unwind(
                    { path: '$banks'})
                .unwind(
                    {
                      path: '$banks.transfers',
                    })
                .project(
                   {'banks.bank_name':1,
                    'banks.transfers.amount' : {
                      $cond: 
                         [
                          {'$banks.transfers.reason' : 'A'},  // if
                           '$banks.transfers.amount',         // then
                           null                               // else
                         ]
                                               }
            })
```

But it gets error

```
MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$banks.transfers.reason'
```

The expected output should be the array of transfers, possibly grouped by "bank_name".

```js
[
 {bank_name:'bank1', 
  transfers: [ {amount:10, reason:'A'}, 
               {amount:1, reason:'A'}
             ]
 },
{bank_name:'bank2', 
 transfers: [  {amount:9, reason:'A'},
               {amount:3, reason:'A'}
            ]
 }
]
```

Comment: Can you add the expected output to the question?

Comment: Do you want `[{ banks: [ { bank_name: 'bank1', ..}, { bank_name: 'bank2', ...} ] }, ...]` or just  `[ { bank_name: 'bank1', ..}, { bank_name: 'bank2', ...} ]` ?

Comment: both of them could be ok for me, I just want that the arrays `transfers` are grouped by `bank_name`